# All snaps broken

Tags: snap, zfs, 20.10

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10, with ZFS.
Since a restart today all my snap apps are broken.

```
$ slack
internal error, please report: running "slack" failed: cannot find installed snap "slack" at revision 32: missing file /snap/slack/32/meta/snap.yaml
```

I tried removing and reinstalling snaps. After that, I'm getting a different error:

```
$ signal-desktop
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_CX14ek//dev: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to further debug this? I'm proficient with the command line, but not that experience with snap or zfs (if it's zfs related)